# Activate different Maven profiles depending on current module?

Tags: maven-2, profile

We have a multi module build with modules using different technologies, like Java and Flex. Is it somehow possible to activate different profiles based on the module that is compiled currently?

I tried it with an activation like

```
<profile>
  <id>flex</id>
  <activation>
    <file>
      <exists>${basedir}/src/main/flex</exists>
    </file>
  </activation>
  ...
</profile
```

But it didn't work, although the use of ${basedir} is [documented in the Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Activation) (this is a bug in Maven). Is there a different possibility to have different activations based on the current module? Or does Maven only allow to activate a profile for all modules or not at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those like myself reading this question looking for answers, this use case now works in Maven 3.

There is was a bug affecting this feature in early versions of 3 (see http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2363) but it works for me correctly using Maven 3.0.4.

Answer (score 5):

After some more research I finally came to the conclusion that this is not possible for two reasons in the current Maven version (2.1.0):

- Maven profiles are not inherited, so you can't define a profile in a parent POM and activate that in a child POM.
- I haven't found a possibility to activate a profile from a POM itself. The  activation does not work with ${basedir} and the property activation response only to system settings, which are globally specified through the -D option.

Comment: Profiles *are* inherited. There's some problem with file activation, but that's different. If you just remove the first 5 words of the first bullet this seems to be correct.

Comment: Sorry, you are wrong. Profile are NOT inherited. You can activate them from a sub folder, but settings are not evaluated again, thus $basedir is only evaluated once for that POM, where it has been defined. See also http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Profile-inheritance-td79841.html, http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Maven-2-inheritance-which-elements-get-inherited-td107049.html and http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-2363 in case you still do not believe me. So it would be nice to remove your down vote.

Answer (score 2):

In 2.2.1, profiles are inherited but the ${basedir} issue is still there.  I'm in the same boat - I need to activate a profile based on the existence of a file in a given project.  My child builds run individually just fine (inherited profile activated by local file existance), but if I run the build from the top parent, they fail because the file isn't found.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to file-based activation, you can try removing ${basedir}. We use it like this:

```
<activation>
   <file>
      <missing>target/jboss/conf/jboss-service.xml</missing>
   </file>
</activation>
```

Comment: Does not work, as with this notation it looks just once at the specified file relative to the parent POM location and does not do it for child POMs again.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this helps, but I solved a similar problem with the following approach:

1. I created and described the profile in the parent POM, which has `activeByDefault=false`. The PluginManagement-Section then contains the configurations for different plugins.
2. The children can reuse this profile, and set `activeByDefault=true`
   This makes the profile active, but still none of the plugins are activated.
3. But fortunately the described plugin configurations are available. You can reuse them in children by defining them in the Plugins-Section. You just provide the group- and the artifactID, and set `inherited=true` for each plugin you want to reuse in the children.

I hope that helps. Sorry for not including any code snippets, but I hope even so the soutions is understandable.

Answer (score -2):

You can set a property in each module that you want to use the profile, and then use "property" activation in your profiles.

Comment: Does not work here. I defined a profile in a parent with a "property" activation and used  the <property> section to defined that property to the respective value to activate the profile. The profile is not activated. Even in case I specify the property with mvn -Dproperty=value. The last works only in case I run it on the parent. Seems like the property must in fact be a system property specified through the -D option and profiles are not inherited at all, which makes this useless for me :-(

Comment: Wrong. The doc explicitly rules out testing a prop set inside a pom.