# How to skip building of the pom in multi-module project

Tags: maven-3

I'm trying to optimize my build process (in development) in term of time to build the whole tree of maven multi-module project. Some of the POM are actually aggregation of sources/libraries that rarelly (and typically) never change. So specific sub-questions are

1. Is it possible to somehow configure maven to not build pom if there are no changes in sources specified in POM:project/build/sourceDirectory attribute?
2. Or is it possible to (at least) conditionally disable maven-bundle-plugin? - it takes most of the time.

Google could not find anything relevant Q#1. Typical solution does not work for #2 - when i try to specify 'executions' for maven-bundle-plugin (like this)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-bundle-plugin.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>osgi-bundle</id>
            <phase>bundle</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>bundle</goal>
            </goals>
```

i receive this error in output

```
[bundle:bundle]
Bundle artifact-id:bundle-id:bundle:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT : The JAR is empty: dot
Error(s) found in bundle configuration
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm aware about following: 
* [Disable a Maven plugin defined in a parent POM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821152/disable-a-maven-plugin-defined-in-a-parent-pom)
(maven-bundle-plugin can't work with 'executions' tag) 
* [Skip execution of a maven plugin if a file does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287451/skip-execution-of-a-maven-plugin-if-a-file-does-not-exist) (maven-bundle-plugin does not have skip confiuration option) 
* [How to skip lifecycle phase in multi maven module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579256/how-to-skip-lifecycle-phase-in-multi-maven-module) (the same as previous) 
* If entire maven-bundle-plugin is moved into profile, maven does not recognize packaging=bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have to admit that (C) Eugene Kuleshov - "Maven generally don't track sources/changes, so it is always a full build."

But, returning back to Java after 5+ on .NET and 5+ years erlier on C++, it looks weird for me that such a common feature like incremental build is not support by widely used tool having a [history](http://maven.apache.org/background/history-of-maven.html) of 10+ years. So I could not spend my time on waiting to rebuild each and every unchanged module in my multi-module project and decided to make customized version of Maven 3.0.4 :)

Feel free to grab it here http://code.google.com/p/maven-onchange-activator/, try and report issues.

Answer (score 0):

Maven generally don't track sources/changes, so it is always a full build. However to disable any plugin you could move it into [profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) and then enable/disable the whole profile, e.g. either conditionally or from the command line.

Comment: Unfortunately that specific solution does not work with maven-bundle-plugin - when it is moved to profile, maven start saying packaging=bundle is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

You should check things like

```
mvn -am
```

in relationship with

```
mvn -pl ...
```

so doing a build like:

```
mvn -am -pl SubModule clean package
```

will build [only those modules which have been changed](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-advanced-reactor-options/) and which needed to be built as a result of a dependency to the change module.

Comment: "pl" is "Build specified reactor projects instead of all projects" - this means I have to know beforehand which projects are changed and explicitly list them in command line. This is definitely not an applicable case.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest switching to Gradle.
Gradle has such support out of the box (no configuration needed) and conversion from Maven should be easy.