# How to share POM fragments between different POMs

Tags: maven, profile, pom.xml

I am currently struggling with Maven: I have a complex project made of several nested modules and for some of those modules, I have similar configurations in the POMs.

I would like to make it clean. Actually, I would like to define a "runnable-jar" common configuration and activate it in some modules.

Here is the POM fragment I would like to share between several projects:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
       <plugin>

        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>

            <!-- Use a custom descriptor, with suffix "bin" -->
            <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/runnable-jar-assembly.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>

            <!-- Add main class to manifest -->
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>

        </configuration>

        <!-- Add build of this package to lifecycle -->
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-runnable-jar</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>

       </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In some of the POMS, I would like to be able to do something like:

```
<!-- Set the main class -->
<properties>
    <mainClass>my.main.Class</mainClass>
</properties>

<!-- Activate runnable jar build -->
<import>src/main/pom/runnable-jar-pom.xml</import>
```

I have searched for a mean to import some XML fragments into a POM, or to define a whole XML nodeset macro.

For what I have found, the closest solution would be to define a profile in the parent POM and activate it in some sub modules by testing the presence of a file. [See this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018720/activate-different-maven-profiles-depending-on-current-module). But I am facing the problem of the `{basedir}` property not being set correctly inherited / set.

I find it very surprising to need a hack to do something so basic (=usual). How do you usually handle this in Maven ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have just discovered something that might solve my problem :

> **A module does not require to be a sub-module of its parent module.**

*Parent* and *sub-module* relationships are separate concepts.

You can specify a parent POM module that is not the actual parent folder in your folder structure, by using the **relativePath** attribute ([as explained in the doc](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance))

In my case, I use the following layout:

> - **main-project**
>
>   - **utils** (parent:*main-project*)
>   - **cli-programs** (parent:*main-project*)
>
>     - **generic-cli** (parent:*cli-programs*; Dummy & empty POM module)
>     - **cli-1** (parent:*generic-cli*)
>     - **cli-2** (parent:*generic-cli*)

Then, in `generic-cli/pom.xml` I can declare a configuration that is common to all my cli programs (like custom test suites, runnable-jar packaging, etc).

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this would be to declare your `<plugin>` code inside `<pluginManagement>` of the parent pom of your multi-module project.  The individual modules can then have a `<plugin>` section which can use this without redeclaring the contents.

Parent pom:

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
              ... all the details...
         </plugin>
         ...
     </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Child poms:

```
     <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
     </plugin>
```

Comment: Nice. I was not aware of that possibility.

Answer (score 1):

[Maven-tiles](https://github.com/repaint-io/maven-tiles) solves this. It's also on the roadmap for maven 3.x, tracked [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5102).

Answer (score 0):

not a total answer but a solution to the basedir problem is to use a common layout of the modules, e.g. root/modules/moduleA root/modules/moduleB.

You can't build the modules formm their own directory anymore, only through thr parent project. But you can work with the profiles.