# Maven profile activation from windows system variable not working

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have the following maven profile configuration

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                <value>dev</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                <value>test</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I have this in `application.properties`

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
```

So `dev` is my default for both spring and maven profiles.

I then have Windows system variable `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` set with a value of `test` to explicitly use the test profile.

[image]

which according to the documentation this should override the `dev` value in my properties file

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html

> 69.5 Set the active Spring profiles
>
> The Spring Environment has an API for this, but normally you would set
>   a System property (spring.profiles.active) or an OS environment
>   variable (SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE). E.g. launch your application with a
>   -D argument (remember to put it before the main class or jar archive):
>
> $ java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=production
>   demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
>
> In Spring Boot you can also set the active profile in
>   application.properties, e.g.
>
> spring.profiles.active=production
>
> **A value set this way is replaced by the System property or environment
>   variable setting**, but not by the SpringApplicationBuilder.profiles()
>   method. Thus the latter Java API can be used to augment the profiles
>   without changing the defaults.
>
> See Chapter 25, Profiles in the ‘Spring Boot features’ section for
>   more information.

Now when I run my Spring application it IS using the `test` profile in Spring, however the maven profile activation does not pick up on this and is still using the `dev` profile.

I have tried setting `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` as the name in the `<property>` element to make sure it wasn't a issue with the lowercase `.` version and the uppercase `_` version but that didn't help.

It DOES work if I supply the variable when I run maven with `-Dspring.profiles.active=test`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**edit**: apparently this also doesn't work when I deploy a war to tomcat where `catalina.properties` contains `spring.profiles.active=test`. The same thing, Spring uses `test` but Maven is still stuck on `dev`.

Comment: maven profile is activated using -P like we inject environment variable with -D. Command be like:
`mvn clean install -Pdev`, which activates `dev` maven profile which in turns activate `dev` spring profile.

Comment: @YogenRai I am looking for a solution that will activate the corresponding maven profile of whatever the spring profile is set as

Comment: Maven controls spring’s profile.. idk if that is achievable .. but good goal :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you want to do is not possible. Profiles can only be activated from the command line or in some cases from the `settings.xml`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23496528/944849). [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9994436/944849) includes links to JIRA issues discussing the challenges and what others have tried to make it work.

System properties are set on the [command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5189966/944849).

Comment: But in the documentation it says it can use a system property `Profiles can be automatically triggered based on the detected state of the build environment. ...... Currently, this detection is limited to prefix-matching of the JDK version, the presence of a system property or the value of a system property.` http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: Properties that activate profiles may come from the `settings.xml` and from the command line, not from files within the app as you're attempting. Expanded on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about activating the profile by using environment variable ?

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                <value>dev</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env.SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE</name>
                <value>test</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```